# Error label innerHTml disappears when image preview is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm working on a django project where I need to permit the user to upload images to the server. Everything's fine except when I want to show an image preview before submitting.

I'm using [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to render the form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["image", "caption"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()

        self.helper.form_method = "post"
        self.helper.form_action = 'add-post'

        self.helper.add_input(Submit("add-post", "Add Post", css_class='btn-primary btn-dark mt-3'))
```

This is the HTML template used for rendering the form:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-8">
            {% crispy form %}
    </div>
</div>
```

This based on the developer inspector in firefox yields the following input HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input" accept="image/*" id="id_image" required="">
<label class="custom-file-label text-truncate" for="id_image">---</label>
```

After hitting the submit button, the `label` gets filled with image name. That's exactly what I want.

However, as mentioned I wanted an image preview before submitting so I took look at the following stackoverflow answer and got what I want:

[preview image before form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608265/15432055)

[Show an image preview before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069481/15432055)

I managed to get an image preview using the following js and HTML:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
    <img id="image-preview">
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-8">
            {% crispy form %}
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    // Show image preview before submitting
    document.getElementById("id_image").onchange = function () {
        var src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
        document.getElementById("image-preview").src = src;
    }
})
```

and now for some reason the label disappears. I tried filling it while reading the image file in the js above but I failed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's better to use URL.createObjectURL instead of using the FileReader

Comment: My solution was based on another answers on stackoverflow. Could you help?

Comment: updated your solution to use object urls instead but it don't solve your issue

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue... so what could I do?